# Search and get equal characters in a String

Tags: java, string

I need to search for a certain String in another character-by-character string and if the characters are the same get such a character;

I'm doing it this way

```
public String searchForSignature(String texto2) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String myString = "", foundString = "";
        myString = "aeiousrtmvb257";
        for (int i = 0; i < texto2.length() || i <= 1000; i++) {
            char c = texto2.charAt(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < myString.length(); j++) {
                if (c == myString.charAt(j)) {
                    foundString = foundString + c;
                }
            }
        }
        return foundString;
}
```

I would like to improve the performance and saw that there are forms and using regular expressions, as I am still a little lay I could not succeed in the way I did.

```
 public String searchForSignature2(String texto2) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("aeiousrtmvb257");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto2);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return matcher.group(1).toString();
    }
```

Does not return anything

//edit

Really, I guess I was not very clear on the question.
Actually I need to get all the characters equal to  "aeiousrtmvb257" the ones that are in the String

I did it that way, now it seems OK, I just do not know if the performance is satisfactory.

```
 public String searchForSignature2(String texto2) {
        String foundString = "";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiousrtmvb257]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto2);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            foundString+=matcher.group();
        }
        return foundString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us an input output example

Comment: I'd create a `Set<Character>` from the char array of `myString` (you seem not to need the position) and then you can just call `contains(c)` or `contains(Character.valueOf(c))` depending on the Java version. As for the regex you'd need a _character class_: `.*[aeiousrtmvb257].*`

Comment: What happens when `i < 1000 && i >= texto2.length()`?

Comment: I think you use a wrong patter. "aeiousrtmvb257" will literally match aeiousrtmvb257. If you want to find the characters one by one, use "[aeiousrtmvb257]"

Comment: why not use [`String.indexOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: @Corentin 
It worked for this pattern, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, by using `Pattern`and `Matcher` this should do the trick:

**Code**

```
private static final String PATTERN_TO_FIND = "[aeiousrtmvb257]";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(searchForSignature2("111aeiousrtmvb257111"));
}

public static String searchForSignature2(String texto2) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_TO_FIND);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto2);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.append(matcher.group());
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

**Output**

> aeiousrtmvb257

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what was the reason behind `texto2.length() || i <= 1000`, but based on the logic in your method, I could suggest the below solution:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(searchForSignature("hello"));
}

public static String searchForSignature(String texto2) {
    String myString = "aeiousrtmvb257";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (char s : texto2.toCharArray()) {
        if (myString.indexOf(s) != -1) {
            builder.append(s);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

> Output: eo

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it, why would you print the string that you found

```
public static String searchForSignature2(String texto2) {
    String maaString = "aeiousrtmvb257";
    String toSearch = ".*" + maaString +".*";
    boolean b = Pattern.matches(toSearch, texto2);

    return b ? maaString : "";
  }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "4erdhrAW BLBAJJINJOI WETSEKMsef saemfosnens3bntu is5o3n029j29i30kwq23eki4"+
    "maoifmakakmkakmsmfajiwfuanyi  gaeniygaenigaenigeanige anigeanjeagjnageunega"+
    "movmmklmklzvxmkxzcvmoifsadoi asfugufngs"+
    "wpawfmaopfwamopfwampfwampofwampfawmfwamokfesomk"+
    "3rwq3rqrq3rqetgwtgwaeiousrtmvb2576266wdgdgdgdgd";
    String myString = searchForSignature2(input);
    System.out.println(myString);
}
```

you need to add .* to tell that your string is surrounded by any char